# Why runs the alert before the redirect?

Tags: javascript, redirect, alert

Can somebody explain here, why I get the alert before the redirect?
and is there a way to switch them?

```
function test() {
  window.location.href="https://www.google.com";
  window.onload = alert("It's loaded!")
}
```

here is an example:

jsbin: https://jsbin.com/zenidafihu/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three different issues here:

## Loading a new location is async

Assigning a new value to `location` won't stop everything until the new page has loaded. It will assign the value and then, at some point in the future, the browser will load the new page. In the meantime, everything will keep going as normal.

## `onload` expects to be passed a function

`alert("It's loaded!")` *calls* the alert function (immediately) and is evaluated as the *return value* of that call (which is not a function). That return value is then assigned to `onload`.

To assign a function, you need to have an actual function, such as:

```
onload = alert.bind(window, "It's loaded!");
```

or

```
onload = function () { alert("It's loaded!"); };
```

## Each page is a separate JS environment

When you leave the page, you create a new execution environment. All variables and data is lost. (Although you can store stuff via localstorage and cookies, and pass stuff to other origins through URLs).

It isn't possible for a page you are leaving to do anything to the page you are going to. You can't set an onload handler for the *next* page.

Answer (score 0):

The redirection won't start until your current Javascript thread has finished executing.  So nothing will happen re the location until the function ends i.e. until the Alert has been dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is asynchronous language. So code for your alert will not wait for complete execution of your first statement i.e. redirection.